# How to merge a none git directory with 90% same files into a repository

Tags: php, git, web-services, github, bitbucket

I started a web project without git.

Now I created a project on bitbucket and commited the a backup from 10 days ago. That means a local copy created with git init add and so one but the latest changes were 10 days in the past.

On my webserver is the current version in about 10% of all files have changed but there is no git initialised at the moment.

So now I want to push all files from my server to the master branch so that I can see the differences.

But how do I accomplish this if the new version is neither a clone nor a seperate branch but just the same folder and file structure as my git repos master with a few changes.

Well I like to switch completely to git but I need to visualize the diffrences between the old and the current version for other developers :(

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a working directory with master checked out, you simply copy the files from the webserver onto it. `git diff` will show you the differences. If you do `git add . && git commit "as per webserver"`, you'll sync your master with the webserver.